# How to get the TextEntry input text tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter and I want to use some code to get the currently entered text of a Textbox.

I currently have the following code.

```
from tkinter import *
def th():
    a = text.get()
    print(a)
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
btn = Button(root, text='hello', command=th())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean? you get it `mystring.get()` as you wrote

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a code I tried. I will edit it!

Comment: Please read some documentation or work through a tutorial before asking such a basic question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command is: `text.get("1.0", END)`
in context:

```
from tkinter import *
def th():
    a = text.get("1.0", END)
    print(a)
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
btn = Button(root, text='hello', command=th) #don't need () for command, or use lambda: th()
btn.pack()  #you forgot to pack your button.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The index of the first character in a text widget is `"1.0"`, not `"0.0"`. The latter works, but only because of how tkinter treats invalid indexes. You also fixed the problem with the `command` attribute but didn't mention it in the explanation. You should point out and explain that, too.